# Interest rates. What is the difference between $I=I_0(1+r)^t$ and $\frac{dI}{dt}=rI$?

Tags: finance

When I was in school, we used this method for generating the amount of money would be in a bank account after $t$ years with interest rate $r$:
$$I=I_0(1+r)^t \text{ where }I_0\text{ is the initial investment}$$
but now in my mathematical finance university course, i'm taught that that it is worked out through using:
$$\frac{dI}{dt}=rI \Rightarrow I(t)=I_0e^{rt}$$
I've noticed that these are not equivalent, so which is correct? I'm assuming their both correct for different methods of working out interest but can someone explain the differences?

Comment: one is simple fixed rate interest over discrete time the later is the continuous compound.

Comment: See [periodic compounding and continuous compounding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest#Periodic_compounding).

Comment: For a fixed annual interest rate (r) you can convert one expression to another: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} I_0 \left( 1+\frac{r}{n}\right)^{nt}=I_0\cdot e^{rt}$$

Comment: @Chinny84:  no, the first is compound interest, but with fixed periods. Simple interest would be a factor $1+rt$

Answer (score 1):

Compare $$I_{n+1}-I_n=rI_n\implies I_n=(1+r)^nI_0\qquad (n\in\mathbb N_0),$$ and $$I'(t)=rI(t)\implies I(t)=\mathrm e^{rt}I(0)\qquad (t\in\mathbb R_+).$$

Answer (score 1):

One of them is in continuous time and the other in discrete time. In one case the amount is multiplied by $1+r$ every time $1$ unit of time passes; in the other case it is multiplied by $e^r$, so $e^r-1$ rather than $r$ is the effective rate.  The nominal rate in the latter case is $r$, and that means the effective rate can be made as close to $r$ as desired by making the amount of time small enough.  Say in a millionth of a second the balance grows by a certain amount.  If it continued growing at that rate in dollars per year, the balance might reach $1+r$ times the initial balance after one year passes.  But the rate of growth doesn't continue to be the same, but increases with the balance, so it ends up *more* than $1+r$ times the original amount.  That's the difference between nominal and effective interest rates if compounding is done every millionth of a second.  That is *almost*, but not quite, the same as continuous compounding.

Comment: Was this down-voted for a reason, or just a random drive-by thing by someone who didn't read it?